# SQL Server 2104\2016 Instead of reading on ONE partitions, reading on two partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a problem with partitions
Instead of reading on ONE partitions, reading on two partitions
I want the reading to take place at necessary partitions
sql server version 2014\2016

```
   --create 2 PARTITION First for 0 value, second to 1 value
    CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_CreditRequest(bit) 
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES(0); 

    --CREATE SCHEME 
    CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_CreditRequest
    AS PARTITION PF_CreditRequest
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); --I want both partition in one file.

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CreditRequest]( 
            [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED, 
            [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_CreditRequest_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)), 
            [FIO] [nvarchar](100) )

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_CreditRequest] ON [dbo].[CreditRequest] 
    ( 
            [IsDeleted] ASC,
            [Id] ASC

    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
    ON [PS_CreditRequest]([IsDeleted]) --split on fild IsDeleted

--some test data
    insert into CreditRequest ([IsDeleted],  [FIO]) values
    (1,'Nike'), (0, 'Jane'), (1, 'Patrik')

--hear is ok
    SELECT  $PARTITION.[PF_CreditRequest](IsDeleted), * FROM  CreditRequest 
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 

    --hear is the problem Instead of reading on ONE partitions, reading on two partitions
    SELECT  $PARTITION.[PF_CreditRequest](IsDeleted),  * FROM  CreditRequest
    WHERE IsDeleted = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an actual split on some column, it should be in the first position in the index:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_CreditRequest] ON [dbo].[CreditRequest]
(IsDeleted, Id)
```

Also note that in order to effectively use such an index, you need to specify a value for the `IsDeleted` column in **every** query that touches this table. Otherwise, all partitions will be affected.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help I create new table for your recommendations `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_CreditRequest] ON [dbo].[CreditRequest] (IsDeleted, Id)`

Answer (score 0):

Another subtle point must be explicitly transformed into bit

SELECT  $PARTITION.PF_CreditRequest,  * FROM  CreditRequest
WHERE **IsDeleted = cast(1 as bit)**

In this case, there will be reading only for one partition